# LNK2019: unresolved external symbol UDSI referenced in function spe_anion_ne

Tags: compiler-optimization

I have written the code in C and when i am loading on Fluent the below type of error is coming

```
 Creating library libudf.lib and object libudf.exp
Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol UDSI referenced in function spe_anion_ne

Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol UDSI

Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol UDSI

Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol UDSI

Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol UDSI

libudf.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Comment: Please help me out of this problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)